# An explanation of randint(2) < 1 in python, I cannot understand what the < 1 does

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

In python, given 
**randint(2) < 1**, 
could someone please explain what the 
**< 1** 
means or does?

I am using IP[y]: Notebook

Please excuse the previous lack of information, this is the code

```
%pylab inline
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
c = randint(2 ,size=100) < 1
s1 = pd.Series(c)
s1.head()
s1.value_counts()
```

Comment: The additional code is **crucial** here; you don't have `random.randint()` but `numpy.random.randint()`, a very different function. And the `size` argument to that function is even more important to the result; it produces an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line produces a truth matrix.

The [`numpy.random.randint()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), with a `size` argument, produces a new `numpy.ndarray` object with `size` elements randomly picked between 0 and 2 (*exclusive*), so in this case 100 0 or 1 values:

```
>>> numpy.random.randint(2, size=100)
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

The `< 1` then produces an array of boolean values (`True` or `False`):

```
>>> numpy.random.randint(2, size=100) < 1
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
        True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
        True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

This array is then converted to a Pandas `Series` object.

Comment: Martijn - probably for the same reason as the accepted answer (question was changed significantly, rendering the 2 answers wrong).  Regardless, yours has been edited to basically be a direct copy of my answer now - perhaps you could have deleted your answer and upvoted the already existing information, rather than needlessly duplicating it?

Comment: @wim: Sorry, I had not, in fact, read your answer at the time I edited  mine. You did add a better alternative, however.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using pylab, this is not the builtin [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) but [`numpy.random.randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html), a different function altogether.

Here `< 1` is used to turn the integer array into a boolean array:

```
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=100)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=100) < 1
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
        True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
        True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

A more pythonic way of achieving the same would have been to do this:

```
randint(2, size=100).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, that really helped. The code was part of a larger code and I needed to understand it before I could go any further. The True/False answer led me to understand the rest of the code. You guys Rock. :)